# Сервер и клиент в одном проекте NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, babel

Всем привет, помогите с решением проблемы. Долго мучился с настройкой рабочей среды для проекта на React, в итоге нашёл статью с простой настройкой [ссылка](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setup-a-react-environment-using-webpack-and-babel) всё вроде прекрасно при изменении файлов всё пересобирается упаковывается и перезагружается в браузере. Но проблема в том что на этом же webpack dev server мне нужно запустить ещё свой файл app.js который условно находится в папке server. Это серверная часть с моим тестовым api к которому я обращаюсь с react, но я не знаю куда и что прописать для того что бы он запускался как серверный и его не пытался собирать webpack и приписывать в клиентский бандл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нафига webpack dev server вообще? запустите в терминальчике `webpack -w` отдельно, а сервер - свой.

Comment: @Darth спасибо за подсказку но в дев сервере ещё livereload работает, хотя твоим способом получилось запустить с 2х консолей, в одной "npm start" для сервера в другой "webpack -w" для сборки.